# How to change the align attribute of image tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, attributes, parent-child, children

I was not able to change the align attribute value of image tag () for my even oddth child of parent div and I browsed but I did not found any thing regarding my issue but then I resolved it by my own.
Here is the Code

```
    const children = document.getElementById('parent').children;
    for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
        let newImg=children[i].children[2];
        if(i%2==0){
            newImg.align="left";
            console.log(newImg.attributes.align)// to check the output in console
        }
        else{
            newsImg.align="right";
            console.log(newsImg.attributes.align) // to check the output in console
        }
    }
```

Comment: CSS should be used for styling... not JavaScript. Learn about the nth-child pseudo class selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

To add an html attribute or modify the value of an existing html attribute from javascript use Element.setAttribute()

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Align attribute in a img tag  is deprecated.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-align